# Should I inform recruiter about the offer I have already accepted

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, ethics

I have already accepted the offer from company **A** which is a great company but my dream has always been to work with company **B**. Now I got an interview call from **B**. I have few questions regarding that. Its always been dream to work for **B**

If I chose to pursue, should I tell about the offer to recruiter of **B** ? (They might not interview me)

Comment: Just curious... by "recruiter of B" do you mean an employee of company B, or a 3rd party recruiter?

Comment: It's Employee of B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pursue B and have time to pursue B before A starts I would say go for it.  You do not know if it is something you would like more than A until you do the interview.

I would not tell the recruiter about the offer unless there is a good reason to do so.  You do not want the recruiter coming in and sabotaging your offer or pulling you from consideration with B which are both potentials.  If you decide to take the job with B just let A know that you will not be accepting after all, there is no reason to tell them about B in any detail other than that you have accepted another offer.

If anyone is concerned about the ethics here just realize that if the situation at Company A  changes and the OP is no longer needed they will not hesitate to retract their offer.  The company could choose to have the OP sign a binding letter that would give company A recourse if the OP changed their mind.  The problem with that is those go both ways, and the OP would then have recourse should Company A pull its offer.  It generally costs much less to recruit someone else than it does to pay them should they no no longer be needed.

Comment: So your answer to the ethical question is "It's OK to treat someone else badly because there's a theoretical possibility they might think about doing the same to you"?

Answer (score 0):

Doing further interviewing after accepting the offer may endanger your new position at Company A. Often it's a small world and you have to assume they might find out about this. See [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13961/4547) for the impact you'd have on them if you back out of an offer, and thus why they might be angry if you appear to be thinking about it.

However, regarding your original question... if you **do** decide to continue interviewing, you should tell the recruiter the full situation. You're already risking burning one bridge. You don't want to burn two.

Answer (score -1):

Don't tell the recruiter and attend the interview. I say this for two reasons.

1)From a purely selfish point of view attending interviews is a good thing and will give you valuable practice.

2)They may also genuinely be able to change your mind and offer you a better position.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a good idea to tell the recruiter about your other offer.  It shows you are in demand, especially if offer A is with a good company.  It will also give you a lot more leverage should they make you an offer.

Comment: That would have been fine if I hadn't accepted the offer. Since I have already accepted the offer and now exploring the opportunity with B, that might impact negatively.

Comment: Why would that be negative, please elaborate @Rahul