# Offered technical test for a job, but close to accepting another job

Tags: interviewing

I have applied to two places, and I have gotten through interview sessions for both. The first company approved and gave me a technical test which I have already finished. The second company approved, but they delayed giving me the technical test. Just today they gave me the technical test, but I am already close to accepting the other job offer because they have a better offer for me in all cases.

How should I approach the second job company saying that I don't mind doing the technical test, but I already have another offer?

Related: [Should I inform recruiter about the offer I have already accepted?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15080/should-i-inform-recruiter-about-the-offer-i-have-already-accepted).

Comment: Are you "already in verge of accepting the job offer" (i.e. haven't accepted it) or "did" (i.e. have accepted it)?

Comment: "I don't mind doing the technical test but I have already accepted [another] offer"  - Don't say this if you want to do the technical test anyway. Just take the test if you want to. If they eventually make an offer you can always refuse at that point.

Comment: As you indicate you have not yet accepted any offer. I edited to clarify. In the future, please edit the body of your question, insted of appending the edit, which is confusing to read.

Answer (score 22):

Unless you've got a signed (by both sides) contact for your new job, **you don't have that job yet**. Things can and do change - plenty of people can tell you the horror stories about the corporate directive coming from on high saying "hiring is frozen" just as they were about to sign a contract.

By all means tell the second company that you have an *offer* that you're on the verge of accepting and they really need to move fast if they're interested, but don't say you've accepted an offer until every bit of paperwork is complete.

Answer (score 4):

As long as no contracts have been signed, you're still a candidate/potential employee to both employers and have no obligations towards them yet. If the first one has made you an offer, you're still a candidate until you actually sign the contract.

As long as you aren't 100% sure if you take the job with the first company, you could still take the test with the second company and see if they come with an interesting offer for you.

As soon as you signed the contract with the first company (if that's what you end up doing), you can simply contact the second company and tell them that you're withdrawing yourself as a candidate. Thank them for the time and effort taken from their side and everything should be fine (and if it's not, that says a lot about that company anyway).